# How add a menu item to the front page of a wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress

Ok so despite the easy sounding name this question has been running circles around me for ages, can't find much decent documentation on it so hopefully the stack will help (that means you XD ). Basically the problem revolves around the use of a bespoke wordpress theme, that has been entirely custom built, well, maybe not entirely but enough to make what should be a simple procedure into a needle-in-a-hay-stack scenario... This is my pea-brain interpretation of what is going on: The theme uses a walker class to traverse the tree structure and pick up on any items that have the 'nav_menu' taxonomy, it then alters each items slug and adds it to the front page menu if it has the right taxonomy using this function:

```
function is_nav_menu( $menu ) {
    if ( ! $menu )
        return false;

    $menu_obj = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $menu );

    if (
        $menu_obj &&
        ! is_wp_error( $menu_obj ) &&
        ! empty( $menu_obj->taxonomy ) &&
        'nav_menu' == $menu_obj->taxonomy
    )
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

I have managed to get my custom post type to appear in the back end by registering it like so in the aptly named 'custom-post-types.php':

```
$mood_board_cpt = new Super_Custom_Post_Type( 'mood-boards', 'Mood Board', 'Mood Boards', $args );
$mood_board_cpt->set_icon('info-circle');
```

However I have examined the so called 'Super'_Custom_Post_Type class constructor and guess what, no where to add a custom taxonomy, also in the file helpfully called 'custom-taxonomies' there happens to be two custom taxonomies that have jack sheet to do with the fabled 'nav_menu' which I want to append to my lovingly nurtured new post type. Anyone know where I can give my post type this taxonomy, baring in mind that due to this being a bespoke theme that I did not design, there is absolutely zilch functionality in the wordpress back end (other than to edit posts of various types), no Apperence -> Menus or any of that useful stuff, so it has to be done purely with code. If anyone could even so much as point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

cheers

Comment: If it were me, I would add it to the menu and use CSS to make it only display on the home page because there are body classes to designate home from other pages.

Comment: Not sure I understand, the problem I have is that I can't work out how  to add it to the menu...

Comment: You should be doing all your menu stuff in the [WordPress Menu editor](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_SubPanel).

Comment: Please read the original post, I clearly state that I do not have access to this editor as it's a bespoke theme that I am updating and did not design

Comment: I get that...you can't convert to a WordPress menu?